# Pass JWT in Azure App Service Performance Test

Tags: azure, jwt, performance-testing, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I have an Azure App Service which I'm trying to set up a performance test on.

I selected `Performance test` and clicked `New`. In the configuration I selected a manual test and set the URL. I left the default settings for all other options.

When I run the test it fails because a JWT is required for authentication.

How can I pass this JWT in my performance test?

Comment: You need to include `HTTP Header` with your request as `Authorization: Bearer ${jwt_token}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pass a JWT token you must setup the performance test with Visua Studio. Go into Visual Studio(there is a link in the Performance test preview). You must select test, then load test. You can configure the load test here. As @Yugal mentioned, In the Headers section add the `Authorization` with `Bearer ${jwt_token}`.